# ASP.NET app communicates with another app via xml messages?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am fairly new to web applications. Could someone explain how I can make an asp.net web app that needs to communicate to another application that only understand XML messages and receives messages via TCP/IP protocol? Do I need to create ASP.NET RestFul API to achieve this.

Comment: kindly be more specific with some requirements so as people can provide you with right articles which will help you for example you can use WCF Services or u can even use web sockets etc etc

Comment: If it's over the web then use WebSockets: https://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-373C. SignalR supports websockets https://www.asp.net/signalr